# Why is my CPU Usage at 100% when using multiprocessing.Pool(processes=half_cpu_cores_available) when using Pytorch and NumPy?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

This is a departure from the usual questions about Python Multiprocessing. Rather, I'm seeing strange behavior and am unsure why. I searched many SO posts, admittedly via Google site:searchoverflow, and could only see the counterexample of "How do I use more cpu"

I have a 16 core processor and am using something like the following:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
    results = pool.map(my_custom_grid_searching_function, list_of_tuples)
```

The custom grid searching function takes the tuple item and then unpacks it feeding it into an algorithm that runs and eventually returns some values. This algorithm leverages NumPy and PyTorch, but is not solely a neural network. Rather a handwritten algorithm wrapping a neural network. (For education honorcode reasons, I cannot divulge much of the source code) Roughly, class with nn -> looping algorithm over data -> loop trains nn and does other stuff -> loop finishes. -> prediction happens.

I'm looking at my computer and it's currently using 100% CPU. More strangely, as the number of spawned Python Processes decrease, the remaining gain % CPU usage.

Am I completely misunderstanding pool - in other words, doesn't pool spawn a process used on a per core basis?

Or is there something else happening here?

I'm looking to cap my utilization to roughly 50 to 75% so I can continue working on other things while this happens in the background.

Any advice or alternative implementations are greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Additional information about my setup:

OS: Windows 11

Run Method: Running via command line python path_to_file.py

CPU Model: AMD Ryzen 9 7950x 16 Core

Comment: Which OS? On many operating systems, 100% cpu means 100% of _one_ CPU, not 100% of _all available_ CPUs.

Comment: And the nature of the work matters immensely here. If you have data that's expensive to serialize and cheap to operate on, multiprocessing may spend all its time in transferring data between processes and basically none on the actual effort. Or if you're using a library (like numpy or scipy or many others) that does its own parallelism, then each subprocess will use more than one core regardless. We really need a [mre] here, giving us enough information to cause the problem ourselves, before we'll be able to give a definite answer.

Comment: Hey Charles, sorry for not including that. I'm running on Windows 11 and viewing this via Task Manager. I've looked at two spots: "Processes" looking at the totals at the top. Also, looking at "Performance" and seeing the graph utilization show "100%" - Additionally, I see it in a non-metric sense - concretely, my computer locks and apps aren't able to be opened. I'll edit my comment with this information as well as other information about how I'm running it.

Comment: Okay, Windows is one where the percentage is divided by the core count (whereas on a Linux-y box it's common for a 16-core system to be at, say, 1400% CPU usage and be perfectly happy/healthy there).

Comment: BTW, do you know how many of those are "real" cores vs hyperthreading-type cores? You might need to divide by more than two (depending; I don't know if AMD plays those games) -- but the bigger concern is still more the nature of the work being done inside the subprocesses

Comment: (and insofar as decreasing the number of processes improves your throughput, it certainly does sound to me like you're at a place where you're getting bottlenecked on interrupts; that's a thing that happens, because process-switching is expensive)

Comment: I'm unsure where to look for the answer to your question about real vs hyperthreading cores. I went to cpu world and entered the model of my cpu and it says 16 cpu cores, 32 threads. I'm assuming they're physical 16. Sorry for my ignorance here.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're interpreting that correctly. So the place I'd worry here is about whether the work done in each process is _really_ subject to the GIL or not; if it's using a C library that's able to spawn its own threads, then more cores can be used than processes you spawn.

Comment: Ah okay, (edit after your clarification) - this might be something with a library I'm using. Under the hood, I'm using pytorch (cpu, not cuda for reasons) and maybe this is not playing well.

Comment: "not playing well" is a bit of a wrong idea. pytorch is parallelized internally. Be happy that you don't need to work with multiprocessing! The library does all the heavy lifting for you. No extra work needed unless you have significant segments of code that are not parallelized

Comment: Numpy (and I suspect torch) may use multi threaded, parallelized code, even if you used a single process.

Comment: I definitely enjoy the performance improvements they have to offer, but I find that I need to speed up the training even more by having a custom grid search function to loop over several hyperparameter combinations. Using the multiprocessing seems to in fact make it faster; 4 hours from 40. My concern is that this freezes up my system.

Comment: You could use a [`multiprocessing.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Semaphore) to have processes acquire `N` entries when they enter an internally parallelized section and acquire 1 entry if they enter an unparallelized section.